# redirect to local page from the server page

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am using blackberry webworks. I want to redirect to local page from the server page. I tried following code : window.location = 'local:///index.html';
but its not working,please let me know the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?  Are you seeing an error, or is the redirect request being ignored.  Suggest using remote web inspector to check for any runtime erros.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "index.html";
```

The application runs in that instance of local:///
If you want to access a file on the Memory Card use file:///

Blackberry decided that localhost and 127.0.0.1 can not be accessed. This leaves local:/// to be bound by the current app.

making an html app you only have 1 window. so you always have to redirect the parent window for what you want to do.
    window.location.href = "local:///index.html";

should work also.

P.S .... local:/// does not work on emulators or ripple. It will work on the actuall BB devices.

Comment: It would be useful to expand a little bit on why this answers the original question.